# How to get subscription list of you-tube subscribers of a YouTube channel?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've tried looking in the following API i got response from Total, but could only get the total count of subscribers.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=subscriberSnippet&maxResults=10&mySubscribers=true&_h=10&

Comment: So are you looking for a list of subscribers instead of the count?

Comment: yes, how to retrieve that? Any idea?

Comment: Added an answer that uses the v3 `subscriptions` endpoint.

Comment: Hi  JAL,
i am also tried but didn't get subscription list in the following api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get which channels that channel subscribed to by this: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=subscriberSnippet%252CcontentDetails&channelId=UC9_eukrzdzY91jjDZm62FXQ&_h=4&

There is no way to get a list of all subscribers for that channel. Cause you'd get that with using forChannelID parameter. But that's not a filter, you have to pick one of the filters while using that parameter. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#filter-parameters

Comment: Actually i created a channel with in this   i want retrieve  subscription list

Comment: could u please see the Question?

Comment: could u please see the Question?for the below link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075117/you-tube-channel-subscription-list-i-get-only-who-have-created-a-channel-for-h

Comment: the url has a few errors. for example, subscriberSnippet does not exist. it would just be "snippet". it would already know what snippet you mean because you are calling to the subscribers url.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the YouTube Data API has an endpoint to retrieve a list of subscribers: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

Your request will look something like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mySubscribers=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: i tried but its show an Error {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.subscription",
    "reason": "subscriberNotFound",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "channelId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}

Comment: i used this api
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mySubscribers=true&key=AIzaSyBhJrnuhBDilWQ2tKEih0Z-j2Do4CW6g9s

Comment: How to get replies comments in you tube?
i tried but i got only main comments.
i want to get these two things. if possible please help me boss

Comment: too simplified. you have to authenticate. ie, you have to install libraries. as you could use it to get somebodys else's and not just your own. some of the API works publically but getting a list of people that subscribe to you or another channel doesnt. much like you couldnt upload without authentication via the libraries. sadly, i cant get that to work myself yet.